# Python. Sort list of dicts by splitting string key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
my_list=[{'c': '1/2014'},
{'c': '1/2015'},
{'c': '10/2014'},
{'c': '2/2014'},
{'c': '3/2014'},
{'c': '1/2011'},
{'c': '2/2011'},
{'c': '3/2011'},
{'c': '6/2014'},
{'c': '5/2014'},
{'c': '10/2014'},
{'c': '2/2015'},
{'c': '4/2015'},
{'c': '3/2015'},
{'c': '5/2016'},
{'c': '1/2017'}]
```

I want order my list by the c key.
The key have two parts: year_counter / year, so first I have to order by year and then by year_counter, inside each year gruop.
At the end I expect to have this:

```
my_list=[{'c': '1/2011'},
 {'c': '2/2011'},
 {'c': '3/2011'},
 {'c': '1/2014'},
 {'c': '2/2014'},
 {'c': '3/2014'},
 {'c': '5/2014'},
 {'c': '6/2014'},
 {'c': '10/2014'},
 {'c': '1/2015'},
 {'c': '2/2015'},
 {'c': '3/2015'},
 {'c': '4/2015'},
 {'c': '11/2015'},
 {'c': '5/2016'},
 {'c': '1/2017'}]
```

What is the best efficent way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I tried this: sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (x['c']).split('/')[::-1], reverse=False). But, I need to consider  tyer counter like an integer. If I use this way I get: [{'c': '1/2011'}, {'c': '2/2011'}, {'c': '3/2011'}, {'c': '1/2014'}, {'c': '10/2014'}, {'c': '10/2014'}, {'c': '2/2014'}, {'c': '3/2014'}, {'c': '5/2014'}, {'c': '6/2014'}, {'c': '1/2015'}....}]
And get {'c': '1/2014'}, {'c': '10/2014'}, {'c': '10/2014'}, {'c': '2/2014'},  instead of {'c': '1/2014'}, {'c': '2/2014'}, {'c': '10/2014'}, {'c': '10/2014'},

Comment: Just convert both to int aswell. `[int(i) for i in v['c'].split('/')][::-1]`. Its not pretty but seems to work.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It work.

Answer (score 0):

I think idea should be to split this `month` and `year` first then apply some sorting algorithm to sort it.

you can use the `underscore` library for that. notice my `fiddle`

https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/96trt0r4/1/

first I splitted your value of `c` to month and year.

```
var split_list = _.map(my_list, function(r){
    return {
      mn : parseInt(r.c.split('/')[0]),
      yr : parseInt(r.c.split('/')[1])
    };
  });
```

then I apply sorting then again joining back to actual field `c` value

```
var sorted_list= _.chain(split_list)
  .sortBy(function(f)
  {
    return f.mn;
  }).sortBy(function(f)
  {
    return f.yr;
  }).map(function(obj)
  {
    return { c: obj.mn+'/'+obj.yr }
  }).value();
```

then I printed on console to check the output.

```
console.log(sorted_list);
```

**Initially I forgot to parse the month and year value to int.  that I have corrected now.**

**UPDATE**
Initially you didn't tag, Python I thought you are looking for json, so I provided the JavaScript solution.

Comment: You forgot `from __future__ import braces` ;)

Comment: Yes sorry, my mistake, no problem.